# Cannot find downloaded artifact in DownloadBuildArtifact task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a pipeline to download and install an artifact from another pipeline. I used DownloadPipelineArtifact task. Here is my yaml:

```
jobs:
  - job:  DownloadLeaf
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

    steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              project: 'Leaf'
              pipeline: 'Leaf'
              buildVersionToDownload: 'latest' 
              branchName: 'refs/heads/develop' 
              downloadType: 'specific'
              itemPattern: '**/*.exe'
              downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
              script: |
                cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                dir
```

Apparently the download worked, because using the dir command the artifact has been identified in the folder where the download was made.

However, I switched the download task to DownloadBuildArtifact @ 0 because of the *warning:##[warning]Please use Download Build Artifact task for downloading Build Artifact type artifact.* After this, despite being displayed in a log that the download was successful, I can't find the artifact using the dir command. I cannot identify what I may be doing wrong. Am i doing something wrong?

Here is my DownloadBuildArtifact task:

```
    steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              project: 'Leaf'
              pipeline: 'Leaf'
              buildVersionToDownload: 'latest' 
              branchName: 'refs/heads/develop' 
              downloadType: 'specific'
              itemPattern: '**/*.exe'
              downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
              script: |
                cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                dir
```

Raw log:

```
*2020-10-24T22:25:44.6766419Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6766756Z Task         : Download build artifacts
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6767272Z Description  : Download files that were saved as artifacts of a completed build
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6767721Z Version      : 0.167.2
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6767954Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6768343Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts
2020-10-24T22:25:44.6768815Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:44.7132255Z ##[debug]Using node path: C:\agents\2.175.2\externals\node\bin\node.exe
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6767362Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=D:\a\_temp
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6799878Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6809455Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6830354Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6834904Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6838469Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ALLOWPARTIALLYSUCCEEDEDBUILDS
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6841199Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BRANCHNAME
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6843928Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUILDTYPE
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6846813Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUILDVERSIONTODOWNLOAD
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6849185Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DEFINITION
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6851986Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DOWNLOADPATH
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6854370Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DOWNLOADTYPE
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6855945Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ITEMPATTERN
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6859404Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PARALLELIZATIONLIMIT
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6873519Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PROJECT
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6876551Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SPECIFICBUILDWITHTRIGGERING
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6882628Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6890968Z ##[debug]loaded 15
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6933342Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6934438Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6935114Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2020-10-24T22:25:45.6935697Z ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
2020-10-24T22:25:45.9788900Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.167.2\node_modules\artifact-engine\lib.json
2020-10-24T22:25:45.9790062Z ##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.167.2\node_modules\artifact-engine\lib.json
2020-10-24T22:25:45.9790858Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2020-10-24T22:25:46.1254482Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.167.2\task.json
2020-10-24T22:25:46.1255912Z ##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.167.2\task.json
2020-10-24T22:25:46.1258030Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4230574Z ##[debug]buildType=current
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4234210Z ##[debug]specificBuildWithTriggering=false
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4237891Z ##[debug]buildVersionToDownload=latest
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4240323Z ##[debug]allowPartiallySucceededBuilds=false
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4243177Z ##[debug]branchName=refs/heads/develop
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4246085Z ##[debug]downloadPath=D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4250041Z ##[debug]downloadType=specific
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4250962Z ##[debug]tags=null
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4253431Z ##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://dev.azure.com/isystemsbr/
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4260547Z ##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION auth param AccessToken = ***
2020-10-24T22:25:46.4347429Z ##[debug]VSTS_HTTP_RETRY=undefined
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8211875Z ##[debug]System.TeamProjectId=8c3c84b6-802b-4187-a1bb-b75ac9c7d48e
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8212703Z ##[debug]Build.BuildId=265
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8258573Z Downloading artifacts for build: 265
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8262012Z ##[debug]set BuildNumber=265
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8291773Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildNumber;issecret=false;]265
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8987923Z Linked artifacts count:  0
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8992590Z Successfully downloaded artifacts to D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:46.8994991Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9008324Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9143509Z ##[section]Finishing: DownloadBuildArtifacts
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9183934Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'CmdLine'
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9186164Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9187490Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9188768Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9189395Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9189994Z ##[section]Starting: CmdLine
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9610741Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9611091Z Task         : Command line
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9611430Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9611980Z Version      : 2.177.1
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9612217Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9612579Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-10-24T22:25:46.9612967Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:48.2360119Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.9.0 commit 6c48b16164b9a1c9548776ad2062dad5cd543352
2020-10-24T22:25:48.4556832Z ##[debug]Entering D:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.177.1\cmdline.ps1.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.4707161Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.177.1\task.json
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5034641Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5099803Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5132208Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.177.1\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5393625Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5873858Z ##[debug]INPUT_FAILONSTDERR: 'false'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5923127Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2020-10-24T22:25:48.5982469Z ##[debug]INPUT_SCRIPT: 'cd D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6062147Z ##[debug]dir'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6109157Z ##[debug]INPUT_WORKINGDIRECTORY: 'D:\a\1\s'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6346759Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\a\1\s'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6430456Z Generating script.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6693519Z ##[debug]AGENT_VERSION: '2.175.2'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6827782Z ##[debug]AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY: 'D:\a\_temp'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.6866567Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\a\_temp'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7195168Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7219612Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7415327Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7529249Z ##[debug] Arguments: '/D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\34a60bd8-2b0b-4817-a73f-9a15c7a05e67.cmd""'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7616224Z ##[debug] FileName: 'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7648172Z ##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'D:\a\1\s'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7742359Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\34a60bd8-2b0b-4817-a73f-9a15c7a05e67.cmd""
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7991894Z  Volume in drive D is Temp
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7992528Z  Volume Serial Number is F090-063D
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7993309Z 
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7993950Z  Directory of D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7994230Z 
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7994896Z 10/24/2020  10:24 PM    <DIR>          .
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7995491Z 10/24/2020  10:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7999544Z                0 File(s)              0 bytes
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8000346Z                2 Dir(s)  11,552,690,176 bytes free
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8061024Z ##[debug]Exit code: 0
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8122555Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8169679Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.177.1\cmdline.ps1.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8756691Z ##[section]Finishing: CmdLine
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8903823Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Checkout core_is/leaf-flowe@leaf/qa to s'
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8909144Z ##[debug]Evaluating: AlwaysNode()
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8910130Z ##[debug]Evaluating AlwaysNode:
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8912646Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8913941Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8915107Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout core_is/leaf-flowe@leaf/qa to s
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9124816Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9125153Z Task         : Get sources
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9125469Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9125797Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9126173Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9127181Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-10-24T22:25:48.9127812Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5279710Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: core_is/leaf-flowe (Bitbucket)
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5286724Z ##[debug]Repository url=https://bitbucket.org/core_is/leaf-flowe
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5287323Z ##[debug]targetPath=D:\a\1\s
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5403584Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout core_is/leaf-flowe@leaf/qa to s
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5493692Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5536041Z Cleaning up task key
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5537617Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5637572Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5741505Z ##[debug]Starting diagnostic file upload.
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5741821Z ##[debug]Setting up diagnostic log folders.
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5750076Z ##[debug]Creating diagnostic log files folder.
2020-10-24T22:25:49.5751523Z ##[debug]Creating diagnostic log environment file.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0152319Z ##[debug]Creating capabilities file.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0262750Z ##[debug]Copying 1 worker diag logs.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0330190Z ##[debug]Copying 1 agent diag logs.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0334272Z ##[debug]Zipping diagnostic files.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0388793Z ##[debug]Uploading diagnostic metadata file.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0490506Z ##[debug]Diagnostic file upload complete.
2020-10-24T22:25:50.0565102Z ##[section]Finishing: DownloadLeaf*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Anton Sizikov,

Thanks for reply, but my problem was another. Unlike Downloadpipelineartifact@2, the DownloadBuildArtifacts@0 task did not work by entering the project name and pipeline for me:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              project: 'Leaf'
              pipeline: 'Leaf'
              buildVersionToDownload: 'latest' 
              branchName: 'refs/heads/develop' 
              downloadType: 'specific'
              itemPattern: '**/*.exe'
              downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

By chance I decided to create the download task through the azure interface, that made the value of the "pipeline" and "project" fields change their value (would it be the ID?).

Anyway, the task looked like this:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
              buildType: 'specific'
              project: '8c3c84b6-802b-4187-a1bb-b75ac9c7d48e'
              pipeline: '4'
              specificBuildWithTriggering: true
              buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
              allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
              downloadType: 'specific'
              itemPattern: '**/*.exe'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Know, I can identify my artifact downloaded using dir command.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log I can see that your artifact was downloaded to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` directory, which is `D:\a\1\a` in your case. Then you run `dir` command there:

```sh
Successfully downloaded artifacts to D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7993950Z  Directory of D:\a\1\a
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7994230Z 
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7994896Z 10/24/2020  10:24 PM    <DIR>          .
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7995491Z 10/24/2020  10:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
2020-10-24T22:25:48.7999544Z                0 File(s)              0 bytes
2020-10-24T22:25:48.8000346Z                2 Dir(s)  11,552,690,176 bytes free
```

[Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) works slightly differently comparing to the old task.

It puts the files into a `<downloadPath>/<artifact-name>` directory. You can see there you've got two of them in your expected path.

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6739).